# Having a problem with Numpy module in vs code terminal

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I want to work with Numpy module in my current project in  VS code, so I ran the code to install it:

[image]

The code was executed successfully, and I can now use the numpy module functions.

But when I run the code in the terminal to check more details about the module I get the following output (I'm Brazilian so the output in Portuguese, but basically it tells there is no module named numpy):

[image]

The command works normally with other modules, but when the module is specifically numpy this error is raised.

Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think you forget to give us the code to install it. So wich command did you make to install numpy ? The correct one is : `pip install numpy`

Comment: while it's frowned upon and I think this can be closed, their installation image wasn't embedded at all (users with low reputation can't embed images)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe NumPy provides any powershell module, it should be called from within Python

```bash
% python
[version stuff]
>>> import numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not run python moduls from terminal directlly, you need to rin the pytjon and import numpy to use:

First type

```
Python
```

To start python, then type:

```
import numpy
```

And use it as you like.

Comment: this is mostly correct; but many modules _do_ provide a program of their same name, though the shell is internally determining they should be called with Python (see [`#!` syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hash-bang)) and they tend to be thin wrappers that just import themselves and do a default operation .. for an example, take a look at [`twine`](https://twine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or `pip` itself (`head $(which pip3)`)

Comment: Yes, those are stand alone programs which you can use moduls or program itself.